# Gcloud ai-platform local predict Error: gcloud crashed (PermissionError): [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gcloud, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I was trying to run a command to test local predict in my computer. However, the command failed every time with this error.

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (PermissionError): [WinError 5] Access is denied`

This is the command:

`gcloud ai-platform local predict --model-dir model_final --json-instances image_b64.json --framework tensorflow`

I am positive 101% positive that I have followed everything in the doc by Google.

1. First, the command required a model file to be saved in [TensorFlow SavedModel format](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/exporting-savedmodel-for-prediction#understanding_training_graphs_and_serving_graphs), which, since I use Keras, I can just do `model.save("model_final")`.

> If you have used Keras for training, use tf.keras.Model.save to export a SavedModel

So I did, at it only output a single file, so I can only assume it's the file to be placed in the --model-dir parameter. I admit doing `model.save("model_final")` created a file, not a dir, which is a bit weird but [the document for Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model) just said use that so there is no way I could be wrong.

And also:

> If you export your SavedModel using tf.keras.Model.save, then you do not need to specify a serving input function.

> If you export a SavedModel from tf.keras or from a TensorFlow estimator, the exported graph is ready for serving by default.

2. The "image_b64.json" file follows [this format](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/overview#prediction_input_data):

`{"image_bytes":{"b64": base64_jpeg_data )}}`

So after 3 hours and having followed everything required by Google, and somehow the gloud still throws me that error. And, yes, of course I have run the command line under Administrator Mode. I also tried it in two of my computers, and I got the same error. I am using Windows, Tensorflow 1.15.

Can anyone point out what is the problem with my implementation, or Google Doc/Keras is just lack lustering. Thank you.

Comment: I am using tensorflow-directml so I cannot upgrade to tensorflow 2. The easy solution would be to load the tf1 model in tf2 (use virtual environment or something), then save the model from tf2.

That's how to "export a SavedModel". However, even with that, the local predict still results in that error.

Comment: Have you tried to supply `gcloud` command with [--verbosity](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity) flag, boosting the log level that might help to expand the permission error?